# Unable to run xUnit Test with Code Rush runner in VS 2012 without an exception

Tags: .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, devexpress, coderush

When I create a unit test project with DevExpress in VS2012 it fails right out of the box with an exception in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core`. Adding an `Assert` so the Sub actually does something doesn't help. No amount of building/rebuilding the project helps, nor does Reloading DevExpress. The code is simple:

```
<TestClass()> Public Class UnitTest1
    <TestMethod()> Public Sub TestMethod1()
        Assert.IsTrue(True)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm guessing something is misconfigured, but I have no idea what. The exception and full output are below.

```
Testing started:  

Total tests: 1, filtered: 1  

Exception:  
Message: An error occurred while initializing the settings provider named 'RunConfiguration'.  
Error: Invalid settings 'RunConfiguration'. Unexpected XmlElement: 'SolutionDirectory'.  
Source: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core  
StackTrace:  
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.RunSettings.<>c__DisplayClass2.<CreateLazyThrower>b__1()  
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.TestPluginsFramework.LazyExtension`2.get_Value()  
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.RunSettings.GetSettings(String settingsName)  
    at CR_VSTesting.Executor.Run(ExecuteTestData data, RunSettings settings, IEnumerable`1 testCases)  
    at CR_VSTesting.Executor.Execute(ExecuteTestData data)  
InnerException:  
Exception:  
Message: Invalid settings 'RunConfiguration'. Unexpected XmlElement: 'SolutionDirectory'.  
Source: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel  
StackTrace:  
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.RunConfiguration.FromXml(XmlReader reader)  
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.RunConfigurationSettingsProvider.Load(XmlReader reader)  
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.RunSettings.LoadSection(XmlReader reader, SettingsProviderExtensionManager settingsExtensionManager, Boolean reload)  
No tests found.  
Duration : 0.8022362
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something in CodeRush v14.2.6.0 is conflicting with Visual Studio 2012. I confirmed that this works fine in 2013. Disabling the unit test functionality in CodeRush solves the issue. To disable this, go to DEVEXPRESS > Options... > Unit Testing, and then uncheck the "Enable Unit Tests Service" checkbox.